# Allocate memory based on filesize has not the correct number?

Tags: c, file, pointers, counter, filesize

I want to store the content of my file in a dynamic string pointer value.
Here is my Code:

```
    char *strPtr = NULL;
    char tmpChar = "";
    inputFile = fopen(input_file, "r");

    fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);   // seek to end of file
    fileSize = ftell(inputFile);    // get current file pointer
    rewind(inputFile);
    strPtr = (char*) realloc(strPtr, fileSize * sizeof(char));
    int counter = 0;

    while ((tmpChar = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF)
    {
        strPtr[counter] = tmpChar;
        counter++;
        if (counter == fileSize)
            printf("OK!");
    }
    printf("Filesize: %d, Counter: %d", fileSize,counter);
```

Now to my Problem ... With the last printf I get 2 different values for example: Filesize 127 & Counter 118.
Addtionally at the END of my strPtr-Variable there is a wrong input like  "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýýüe".

Notepad++ also says at the end of the file that I am at postion 127, so whats the Problem about the 118?

Comment: did you declare `tmpChar` as `int` as you should have

Comment: no.  char tmpChar = "";

Comment: and also open it in binary mode

Comment: and terminate the srring... please provide a proper [mcve], this isn't one yet

Comment: What is strPtr? How is it declared? With what value is it initialiazed, and why are you realloc-ing instead of malloc-ing?

Comment: Null, I personally always use realloc instead of malloc. Should be the same result than mallocing the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the file in text mode (the default) on Windows, the CRT file functions will convert any `\r\n` to `\n`. The effect of this is every line you read will be 1 byte shorter than the original with \r\n.

To prevent such conversions, use "binary" mode, by adding a "b" mode modifier, e.g. "rb".

```
inputFile = fopen("example.txt", "rb")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019

> In text mode, carriage return-linefeed combinations are translated into single linefeeds on input, and linefeed characters are translated to carriage return-linefeed combinations on output.

> ```
> while ((tmpChar = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF)
> {
>     strPtr[counter] = tmpChar;
>     counter++;
>     if (counter == fileSize)
>         printf("OK!");
> }
> ```

Additionally, this loop, assuming the file does not *contain* any NULL values will not null terminated your string. If you later use `strPtr` in such a way that one is expected (e.g. `printf`, `strcmp`, etc.) it will read past the valid range.

If you do want a null terminator, you need to add one after. To do this you also need to be sure you allocated an extra byte.

```
realloc(strPtr, (fileSize + 1) * sizeof(char));
while (...
strPtr[counter] = '\0'; // Add null terminator at end.
```

To handle files/strings that might contain nulls you can't use null terminated strings at all (e.g. use `memcmp` with size instead of `strcmp`).

Comment: Thanks! That solved the Counter problem!
Do you also know the reason for the "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýýüe" at the end of the variable?

Comment: What do you mean by the "END" here, `strPtr[size - 1]`? I think you are maybe also going past the end.

Comment: You solved all the problems that was exactly what i searched for! Thank you!